# net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) at frontend

Tags: magento2, xampp, magento2.3.6

I have created store view in `French and German language`, i have installed both language package and deployed it, but when I change the store language from the frontend, language is changed but in console, it give many errors,

like below image,

[image]

**I'm using ubuntu XAMPP**

Comment: Try to deploy static content again using command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE fr_FR` and flush cache. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @RahulBarot I have run the same code for both languages, still get same error

Comment: Have you checked error log of server? Also, I think you are accessing https type on local you may require to install it and change URL according to it. Give some nice name like https://demo.com by giving virtual host.

Comment: @RahulBarot its working without error by using your given code, thanks

Comment: @R_Solanki Your welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy static content again using command

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE fr_FR`

and flush cache.